# Angular - How to get client's bandwidth on Angular / JavaScript based application without the need to download any file?

Tags: javascript, angular9

We are working on Angular based application wherein we want to get the bandwidth of user's client machine to determine and show appropriate error message while displaying video streaming content on our app.

We have already looked into libraries like - ng-speed-test for the same however what it does is, it downloads a 5 MB file to determine the bandwidth.
In our use case we want to periodically check the bandwidth for that using this is not a suitable option.

**Question** In short we are looking for a way in JavaScript / Angular to know the bandwidth of user's machine without downloading a file and that should support in Google chrome, IE Edge (Chromium), Safari and Firefox.

Any suggestion that meets our case is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

The only way to determine the speed of a network connection is to measure it.

The only way to do that is to transfer a known amount of data along it and time out long it takes.

Comment: thank you for response. Could you suggest any library to check client side bandwidth in angular/JavaScript